# calculating sum based on customed rules in the data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Preferably using `data.table` in R: I want to calculate the sum of `DIAM` by `ID`, `CYCLE #` based on the following rules:

1. if any of the `DIAM` for particular subject cycle is presented as `NE` then the `SUM` cant be calculated (must return `NA`)
2. if any of the `DIAM` is presented as `NA`, then calculate the sum ignoring the `NA` (i.e. as if it is 0)
3. if none is `NA`, then calculate the sum as normal

Also i would like to substitute `CYCLE` number to numeric with `BASELINE` representing 0.

```
dfin <- 
ID    CYCLE     NUM   DIAM
1     BASELINE  1      8
1     BASLEINE  2      4
1     CYCLE 1   1      6
1     CYCLE 1   2      2
1     CYCLE 2   1      6
1     CYCLE 2   2      NE
1     CYCLE 3   1      6
1     CYCLE 3   2      NA

dfout <- 
ID    CYCLE     SUM
1     0         12
1     1         8
1     2         NA
1     3         6
```

This need to be applied for every subject. There are many cycles there but this just an example.

Comment: Can you add data using `dput`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option.  Grouped by 'ID', and the `match`ed index of 'CYCLE' (as showed in the expected output), change the "DIAM" values to `NA` if `any` of 'DIAM" have "NE", then `summarise` by taking the `sum` of 'DIAM' while making sure that if all of the values are `NA` return `NA`

```
library(tidyverse)
dfin %>% 
  group_by(ID, CYCLE = match(CYCLE, unique(CYCLE))-1) %>% 
  mutate(DIAM = as.numeric(replace(DIAM, any(DIAM== "NE"), NA))) %>%
  summarise(SUM = NA^all(is.na(DIAM)) * sum(DIAM, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [?]
#     ID CYCLE   SUM
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0    12
#2     1     1     8
#3     1     2    NA
#4     1     3     6
```

---

Or use an `if/else` condition after the `group_by` step

```
dfin %>%
  group_by(ID, CYCLE = match(CYCLE, unique(CYCLE))-1)  %>% 
  summarise(SUM = if("NE" %in% DIAM) NA else sum(as.numeric(DIAM), na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or using the same logic with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfin)[, .(SUM = if("NE" %in% DIAM) NA_real_ else 
   sum(as.numeric(DIAM), na.rm = TRUE)), .(ID, CYCLE = rleid(CYCLE)-1)]
#   ID CYCLE SUM
#1:  1     0  12
#2:  1     1   8
#3:  1     2  NA
#4:  1     3   6
```

#### data

```
dfin <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
  CYCLE = c("BASELINE", 
 "BASELINE", "CYCLE 1", "CYCLE 1", "CYCLE 2", "CYCLE 2", "CYCLE 3", 
 "CYCLE 3"), NUM = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), DIAM = c("8", 
 "4", "6", "2", "6", "NE", "6", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), 
 class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: is there a way to do the same thing using data.table? as i am working on a server with limited number of packages there and not easy to install new package

Comment: that is great! May I add another rule which is if any of the BASELINE DIAM  is NA then SUM is NA for all cycles. if you could, you comment on this here rather than me asking a separate question?

Comment: You mean if the CYCLE = BASELINE & DIAM = NA, SUM for all CYCLE (not just BASELINE) should be 0?

Comment: @Rage yes. Coz if baseline wasn't evaluated then no data can be used

Comment: Pls check if the update does what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
# Data created
dfin<-data.table("ID" = rep(x = 1,times = 8),"CYCLE" = c("BASELINE","BASELINE","CYCLE 1","CYCLE 1","CYCLE 2","CYCLE 2","CYCLE 3","CYCLE 3"),
                 "NUM" = rep(x = c(1,2),times = 4),"DIAM" = c(8,4,6,2,6,"NE",6,NA))

# CYCLE transformed
dfin[,CYCLE := as.numeric(ifelse(CYCLE == "BASELINE","0",
                     substr(x = CYCLE,start = 7,stop = 7)))]

# SUM computed
dfin2<-dfin[,.(SUM = if(CYCLE == 0){
  NA_real_
} else if("NE" %in% DIAM){
  NA_real_
} else {
  sum(as.numeric(DIAM),na.rm = T)
}),by = c("ID","CYCLE")]

# IDs with CYCLE = 0 present have SUM updated to NA 
dfin2[ID %in% ID[which(CYCLE == 0)],SUM := NA]
```

Hope this helps!